# Remove duplicate words between lists

Tags: bash, shell-script

Remove duplicate words from between lists example:

We have two lists; the first list contains:

```
a
b
c
d
```

The second list contains:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

I want to make a comparison between the first and second lists,
removing the matches contained in both, resulting in this:

```
e
f
```

I couldn't find a solution to do that with bash, but I did find one in python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists/7961390#7961390

Comment: Have you tried something so far? Folks here will be more inclined to help if you show some effort.

Comment: I couldn't find a solution to do that with bash
But a solution was found in Python
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7961390/13079083

It's similar to what I want to do but I don't know a function like set in BASH

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two files comparison in bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397655/two-files-comparison-in-bash-script)

Comment: It looks like it but the list must be similar to give correct results
list a
a \ nb \ nc \ nd ...
list b
a \ nb \ nc \ nd \ ne ...
If the letters are not in order, it will give false and incomplete results
Especially if you use long words in the comparison, all results will be incorrect

Comment: The grep solution linked will remove all duplicate lines. The files do not need to be "similar" to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `diff` using `--GTYPE-group-format=GFMT` option. From `man diff` :

```
--GTYPE-group-format=GFMT
    format GTYPE input groups with GFMT

LTYPE is 'old', 'new', or 'unchanged'.
    GTYPE is LTYPE or 'changed'.

    GFMT (only) may contain:

%<     lines from FILE1

%>     lines from FILE2

%=     lines common to FILE1 and FILE2
```

In your case, you can use `diff --new-group-format='%>' --unchanged-group-format='' list1 list2`

```
$ cat list1
a
b
c
d

$ cat list2
a
b
c
d
e
f

$ diff --new-group-format='%>' --unchanged-group-format='' list1 list2
e
f
```

### Explanation

- The `--new-group-format='%>'` will output any new entries from FILE2 (`%>`) that doesn't exist in FILE1.
- The `--unchanged-group-format=''` will prevent `diff` to print any identical lines.